# Reverse engineer exe or DLL for C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, decompiling

I want to ask if there is any program I can use to decompile an exe or dll, to C# code, because, by mistake I erased the source code and I want to make modifications.

Comment: Maybe i can [google](http://bit.ly/1fUdi6d) this for you?

Comment: "because by mistake I erase the source code and I want to make modification" - sounds legit...

Comment: Is it an exe or is a dll? Can't you tell? Anyway, the source code is in your revision control system.

Comment: Why do you even ask a question here? Its much easier to google this?!?!

Comment: I will try reflector as it is suggested here. I have both exe & dll. Ok I admit it's sounds illegal but I think 'serious' programs are obfuscated and have encryption or other security messures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reflector` is a decent disassembler But it is a paid software these days, but worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

[ILspy](http://ilspy.net/) is yet another IL decompiler, that is open source.